# How to keep google chrome extension running even if I open an another tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am running the chrome extension in browser action. As a developer, I am opening the inspect the popup and running, so it will stay open in the current tab. When I open the other tab, the "inspect the popup" which I open in the developer mode is getting closed. Is there a way to make the "inspect the popup" run continously even if I open the other tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't; normally, any sort of focus loss will cause the popup to close.

While inspecting the popup, it's less sensitive to focus loss for ease of debugging, but changing the tab still causes it to close (and therefore, the Dev Tools window attached to it closes as well).

My guess is that some important expectations of the Chrome API are lost if the current tab changes after invoking the popup. For example, `"activeTab"` permission will break. That, or it may be simply a bug.

Bottom line: this will never actually happen in normal use, so this inability isn't that important. If you need to access multiple tabs, open them in separate window: switch to it won't cause an inspected popup to close.

Comment: I am making the "XMLHttpRequest()" request to the set of URLs(100). If I open them in a  separate window, for every new request it is opening a new tab like 100 tabs. So I am running using "inspect popup". Can I run the set of URLs in a single tab request like for 100 URL requests it should process only in one tab i.e; in one tab without opening 100 tabs?

Comment: I don't understand the question. XHR has nothing to do with opening tabs.. By the way you can open a tab from the popup without closing it by setting `tabs.create` options to not be active (open in background) if that helps.

Comment: I am new to Javascript.I have 100 URLs. I am using "XMLHttpRequest()" to get the response from those URLs. Can I open a tab in the google chrome and make those URLs run one after the other? I tried with a for loop like "for(i = 0; i < urls.length;i ++){ window.open(url[i]) }" but the problem is for every run it is opening a new tab. How can I make all the URLs run by opening only one tab?

Comment: Use `chrome.tabs` API, specifically `create` then `update`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Does "chrome.tabs" return data? Because all these URLs give JSON. Is there a way to store the JSON of each URL by using chrome.tabs API?

Comment: Sorry, this is growing beyond what's acceptable for SO comments; if you have further questions, post them as new questions. But please be specific in what you're trying to achieve so that it's not an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).